# upload matplotlib fig onto google cloud bucket

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab

i'm working on jupyterlab from a gcloud dataproc cluster. i'm trying to save a matplotlib file onto the bucket but i get the error that there's no such directory. my code is

```
# create figure and axis objects with subplots()
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
# make a plot
ax.plot(df_opt.year, df_opt.pop, marker='o', color='navy', alpha=0.3)
ax.set_xlabel("Year",fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Population",fontsize=14, color='navy', alpha=0.8)
# twin object for two different y-axis on the sample plot
ax2=ax.twinx()
# make a plot with different y-axis using second axis object
ax2.plot(df_opt.year, df_opt.gdp, marker='o', color='mediumvioletred', alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_ylabel("GDP per cap",fontsize=14, color='mediumvioletred')
plt.show()
# save the plot as a file
fig.savefig("gs://mybucket/popgdp.png")
```

the error I get is "No such file or directory: gs://mybucket/popgdp.png"

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

savefig() is not capable to save directly to a GCS bucket. What you can do is to save it locally first then copy the file to GCS. For more details, see the document for [uploading a file in GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python).

```
from google.cloud import storage

# create figure and axis objects with subplots()
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
# make a plot
ax.plot(df_opt.year, df_opt.pop, marker='o', color='navy', alpha=0.3)
ax.set_xlabel("Year",fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Population",fontsize=14, color='navy', alpha=0.8)
# twin object for two different y-axis on the sample plot
ax2=ax.twinx()
# make a plot with different y-axis using second axis object
ax2.plot(df_opt.year, df_opt.gdp, marker='o', color='mediumvioletred', alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_ylabel("GDP per cap",fontsize=14, color='mediumvioletred')
plt.show()
# save the plot as a file
fig.savefig("gs://mybucket/popgdp.png")


bucket_name = "mybucket"
destination_blob_name = "popgdp.png"
source_file_name = "your_local_file_path/popgdp.png"

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```